# How do I make my bot reply to users on discord.py VSC?

Tags: discord.py

Ok, so I have tried over 674 types of code, and none of them work. All I want is to make my bot reply to a message if a user says "?Pizza" and it replies "Wassuuuuuup"

Any help?

Comment: did you attempt to RTFM? what are the "674" types of code you have tried, what are the results? what makes it "not work"

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for

Comment: Surely, if you tried *over 674 types of code*, you could include at least one or two of those tries in your post. It's clear that you haven't actually tried **674** times, but when you include no effort at all, it's pretty hard to believe that you tried anything. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting, as was suggested when you created your account.

Comment: Yeah, 674 was exaggeration, I have tried a lot tho.

Comment: There are bot examples on the docs - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/, you can make it repond by doing eg `await ctx.send('Wassuuuuuup')`

Answer (score 1):

discord.ext.commands:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

token = ""

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?")

@bot.command()
async def pizza(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Wassuuuuuup")

bot.run(token)
```

on_message():

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
  if msg.author.id == bot.user.id:
    return
  if msg.content.startswith("?pizza"):
    await msg.channel.send("Wassuuuuuup")
```